# Is there XIB files limit?

Tags: xib, nib

Hi i'm working on project that have a table view with 10 controllers every controller have 3 subviews so i'll have more than 20 xib files.  Could this be a problem when i submit my application at the app store. I wonder if there any limit  for xib files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't forsee any reason why this would be a problem :)

You can give Apple a buzz if you want to check, maybe they can offer further advice.

http://developer.apple.com/contact/